# how to make ip address of server static

Tags: web-services, client, client-server, multipeer-connectivity, vs-web-application-project

I have made a client-server desktop application in java with following parts

- Server (Teacher)
- Client (Student)

Multiple Clients connect to Server using Server's IP Address and port.

But Server's IP address does not remains same and clients can not

connect to server anymore.

Can anyone tell that how to

1.make server IP address fixed so that it does not change

- when disconnected and reconnected to router
- when connected to another router

2.if above can not be accomplished how to broadcast changed IP address 
of server to clients

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At home I have achieved this by turning off the Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) on the switch/router so that the IP's are fixed.

Note that the IP for the server inside of your home/company network and the IP exposed outside of your network may be different.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more about your note. I have no company. I just have a pc for server and a router. thanks

Comment: sure. is the pc connected to the server through your local network/at home? or is the pc connected to the server from some other internet connection, like from a starbucks wifi?

Comment: The pc (on which Server program is running) is connected to a WiFi. @kilogic

Comment: And how do you usually connect to the server, on the same WIFI connection, or from far away on some other WIFI connection/internet?